# Странно отображается страница

Tags: веб-программирование, php, html

Доброе время суток! У меня возникла странная ситуация. Есть страница, которая выводится так:

[image: Imgur]

Проблема в том, что таблица должна выводиться ДО кнопки Добавить/скрыть.

```
<body><h1><?php print $title; ?></h1<div><?
$db_table_to_show = "_group";
$qr_result = mysql_query("select * from " . $db_table_to_show)
    or die(mysql_error());

echo '<table class="tablesorter">';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Номер группы</th>';
echo '<th>Специальность</th>';
echo '<th>Курс</th>';
echo '<th>Количество студентов</th>';
echo '<th>Тип группы</th>';
echo '<th>Форма обучения</th>';
echo '<th>ГФ</th>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</thead>';

echo '<tbody>';
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result)){ 
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $data['nomer'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $data['specialnost'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $data['kurs'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $data['kolichestvo'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $data['_type'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $data['forma'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $data['_date'] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }echo '</tbody>';?> <button onClick="hide_show();return false;" id="link1">Добавить</button></div><div id="div1" style="display:none"><h3>Добавление группы</h3><form action="../lib/add/add.php" method="POST">Номер группы: <input type="text" name="nomer" value="" maxlength="4">Специальность: <input type="text" name="specialnost" value="" maxlength="3">Курс: <input type="text" name="kurs" value="" maxlength="15">Количество студентов: <input type="text" name="kol" value="" maxlength="3"><br>Коммерция: <input type="checkbox" name="kom">Форма обучения:<select name="forma"><option value="Дневное">Дневное</option><option value="Заочное">Заочное</option></select>ГФ: <input type="text" name="gf" value="2013"><input id="button" name="submit1" type="submit" value="Отправить"></form></div><br><? echo '_______________________________________________________________________________________________';?></body>
```

Comment: По-моему, это из-за отсутствия закрывающего тега </table>

Comment: Большое спасибо!!! Извините меня за невнимательность((((((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '</tbody>';?>  <button onClick="hide_show();return false;" id="link1">Добавить</button></div>
```

1. нету открывающего тега `<div>`.
2. также закройте таблицу `</table>`.

Comment: Спасибо. Но открывающий тег     <div> есть, в первой строке кода.